# Will I have any issues painting in the Forms Non Client Area on Windows 8 machines?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, gdi+

I don't have Windows 8 to test it out, although I figure I am going to have to check myself anyway to make sure their for sure will not be any issues.

I am using an approach I found on the code project to add controls into the non client area of a WinForm. I am using Windows 7 right now and it works great.

The NCA I am talking about is the title bar. The approach basically allows you to add controls to the title bar using Vista's Desktop Window Manager (DWM).

My biggest worry is that it does not use the same painting techniques and it will cause my application to look silly on windows 8 desktop.

Comment: How about giving it a try? For a zero-costs approach, use e.g. VMware and a Windows 8 Trial version.

Comment: You will have issues. I have written many apps that worked this way just fine on Windows Vista and Windows 7. These apps simply display a black screen when used on Windows 8.